# responsive image, maintain original size, resize after stretch window css

Tags: css

I have an image of ***320px x 320px***  and `max-width:620px` for the container `div`

My problem is that I want it to appear at firs,with the original size, then if resize the window, then decrease the proportions of the image.

```css
div.container {
  max-width: 620px;
  background: yellow
}

img {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="containe">
  some text
  <img class="img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x320/33ff99/555555?text" /></div>
```

I can not use `max-width:320px` in the image, because, the image generates dinamically and It usually have some other size values

How can I do it?

Comment: `text-align: center;`  Why center the text, if the text is not?

Answer (score 0):

You could use @media queries, you can read more about them [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp).

If you resize your window let's say smaller than 768px. You could change your image size. The css below will make the image take the full width of the container while keeping its aspect ratio.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #img {
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
  }
}
```